# SqlClient connection factory management, with ninject in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I'm running into this problem currently in my WCF service. "The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool"

Now I understand the error, my question is, what is the proper way to manage the Sql connection in a WCF service using Ninject.

What I have done is this.
In the binding I have

```
 Bind<IConnectionFactory>().To<ConnectionFactory>().InScope(c => OperationContext.Current);
```

And my connection factory looks like this.

```
public class ConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
    private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public SqlConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        if (sqlConnection == null)
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            sqlConnection.Open();

        return sqlConnection;
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

Whenever I need a Sql connection I invoke it with via an IoC container like this.

```
 SqlConnection connection = IoC.Resolve<IConnectionFactory>().GetOpenConnection();
```

My assumption was, that whenever I am dealing with the same request, I would get the same connection back from Ninject, and all connection calls within that request life time will get the same connection. Based on the error, I am assuming this is not happening. Is there a better way of doing this ? Or what is a better connection management paradigm for WCF with ninject ? I feel that making the connection factory a singleton would be the wrong way to go, but that's just my gut feeling.

EDIT: I would like to add that I inject the connection into my repositories like this

```
private readonly SqlConnection connection;

    public RandomRepository(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        connection = connectionFactory.GetOpenConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Making the factory a sigleton is not a problem if you return correct connections. I don't know Ninject much you have to find a correct lifetime manager for your connections - the same connection should be returned for the lifetime of a request.

Comment: Just to add some additional suggestion: Add sqlConnection.Dispose() in CloseConnection()! Otherwise the connection-pooling will not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,
You can install Ninject.Extensions.WCF this provides you appropriate scoping for WCF services. Then you can inject an `SqlConnection` directly into your classes without having to use your connection factory. Simply use a method binding with the appropriate scope. For example with call scope:

```
Bind<ISqlConnection>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IConnectionFactory>().GetOpenConnection()).InCallScope();
```

Ninject will then take care of disposing the connection when your request is out of scope.

Comment: This is the correct approach except that the scope is called InRequestScope() as oppose to InCallScope().

Comment: InCallScope would also work if you have non singleton services.